# XSLT transformation to exclude namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and have an issue with the namespace.
Here is my XML that I have to transform:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://www.softomat.bg/myapp/esb/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <InputRequestID>?</InputRequestID>
    <InputTimeStamp>?</InputTimeStamp>
        <OrderInput>

            <Recipient>?</Recipient>

            <PortInFlag>?</PortInFlag>

            <Donor>?</Donor>

            <FMCFirstCompleteFlag>?</FMCFirstCompleteFlag>

            <CreatedOn>?</CreatedOn>

            <ACSBillingAccountIntegId>?</ACSBillingAccountIntegId>

            <OrderType>?</OrderType>

            <OrderReason>?</OrderReason>

            <CustomerFirstName>?</CustomerFirstName>

            <CustomerName>?</CustomerName>

            <AgreementNum>?</AgreementNum>

            <AgreedbyOwner>?</AgreedbyOwner>

            <OriginalReceived>?</OriginalReceived>

            <AgreementSignDate>?</AgreementSignDate>

            <BusinessContactFirstName>?</BusinessContactFirstName>

            <BusinessContactLastName>?</BusinessContactLastName>

            <UserID>?</UserID>

            <FMCMNPRequestId>?</FMCMNPRequestId>

            <LegalContactFirstName>?</LegalContactFirstName>

            <LegalContactLastName>?</LegalContactLastName>

            <CreatedBy>?</CreatedBy>

            <Comments>?</Comments>

            <IntegrationID>?</IntegrationID>

            <OrderId>?</OrderId>

            <ReferenceOrder>?</ReferenceOrder>

            <Status>?</Status>

            <OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>?</OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>

            <TriggerScript>?</TriggerScript>

            <OrderSource>?</OrderSource>

            <CustomerSegment>?</CustomerSegment>

            <CustomerSubsegment>?</CustomerSubsegment>

            <CustomerIdNumber>?</CustomerIdNumber>

            <CustomerIdType>?</CustomerIdType>

            <Priority>?</Priority>

            <CustomerCode>?</CustomerCode>

            <Urgent>?</Urgent>

            <SalesPersonEmail>?</SalesPersonEmail>

            <NotificationPhoneNumber>?</NotificationPhoneNumber>

            <NotificationEmail>?</NotificationEmail>

            <ASAP>?</ASAP>

            <CustomerNotificationChannel>?</CustomerNotificationChannel>

            <OrderCreatorEmail>?</OrderCreatorEmail>

            <PrevCustomerRef>?</PrevCustomerRef>

            <VIPFlag>?</VIPFlag>
        </OrderInput>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ser="http://www.softomat.bg/myapp/esb/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://bre-sc/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
                <xsl:copy-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/OrderInput" />
            </ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://bre-sc/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
        <OrderInput **xmlns:ser="http://www.softomat.bg/myapp/esb/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer"**>
            <Recipient>
                ?
            </Recipient>
            <PortInFlag>
                ?
            </PortInFlag>
            <Donor>
                ?
            </Donor>
            <FMCFirstCompleteFlag>
                ?
            </FMCFirstCompleteFlag>
            <CreatedOn>
                ?
            </CreatedOn>
            <ACSBillingAccountIntegId>
                ?
            </ACSBillingAccountIntegId>
            <OrderType>
                ?
            </OrderType>
            <OrderReason>
                ?
            </OrderReason>
            <CustomerFirstName>
                ?
            </CustomerFirstName>
            <CustomerName>
                ?
            </CustomerName>
            <AgreementNum>
                ?
            </AgreementNum>
            <AgreedbyOwner>
                ?
            </AgreedbyOwner>
            <OriginalReceived>
                ?
            </OriginalReceived>
            <AgreementSignDate>
                ?
            </AgreementSignDate>
            <BusinessContactFirstName>
                ?
            </BusinessContactFirstName>
            <BusinessContactLastName>
                ?
            </BusinessContactLastName>
            <UserID>
                ?
            </UserID>
            <FMCMNPRequestId>
                ?
            </FMCMNPRequestId>
            <LegalContactFirstName>
                ?
            </LegalContactFirstName>
            <LegalContactLastName>
                ?
            </LegalContactLastName>
            <CreatedBy>
                ?
            </CreatedBy>
            <Comments>
                ?
            </Comments>
            <IntegrationID>
                ?
            </IntegrationID>
            <OrderId>
                ?
            </OrderId>
            <ReferenceOrder>
                ?
            </ReferenceOrder>
            <Status>
                ?
            </Status>
            <OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>
                ?
            </OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>
            <TriggerScript>
                ?
            </TriggerScript>
            <OrderSource>
                ?
            </OrderSource>
            <CustomerSegment>
                ?
            </CustomerSegment>
            <CustomerSubsegment>
                ?
            </CustomerSubsegment>
            <CustomerIdNumber>
                ?
            </CustomerIdNumber>
            <CustomerIdType>
                ?
            </CustomerIdType>
            <Priority>
                ?
            </Priority>
            <CustomerCode>
                ?
            </CustomerCode>
            <Urgent>
                ?
            </Urgent>
            <SalesPersonEmail>
                ?
            </SalesPersonEmail>
            <NotificationPhoneNumber>
                ?
            </NotificationPhoneNumber>
            <NotificationEmail>
                ?
            </NotificationEmail>
            <ASAP>
                ?
            </ASAP>
            <CustomerNotificationChannel>
                ?
            </CustomerNotificationChannel>
            <OrderCreatorEmail>
                ?
            </OrderCreatorEmail>
            <PrevCustomerRef>
                ?
            </PrevCustomerRef>
            <VIPFlag>
                ?
            </VIPFlag>
        </OrderInput>
    </ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I'm trying to remove the namespace in InputOrder of the result but it not works for me. Could anyone help me with XSLT? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by making a minor change in the stylesheet as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:ser1="http://bre-sc/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer"
            xmlns:ser="http://www.softomat.bg/myapp/esb/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/OrderInput" />
                </ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have moved the `xmlns:ser` inside the `<soapenv:Envelope>` from the `<xsl:stylesheet>` node and also created a separate alias `xmlns:ser1` for the existing URL. This will ensure the namespaces applied become attributes of the parent node. The output transformed XML is as below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:ser="http://www.softomat.bg/myapp/esb/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer"
    xmlns:ser1="http://bre-sc/ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformer"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
            <OrderInput>
                <Recipient>?</Recipient>
                <PortInFlag>?</PortInFlag>
                <Donor>?</Donor>
                <FMCFirstCompleteFlag>?</FMCFirstCompleteFlag>
                <CreatedOn>?</CreatedOn>
                <ACSBillingAccountIntegId>?</ACSBillingAccountIntegId>
                <OrderType>?</OrderType>
                <OrderReason>?</OrderReason>
                <CustomerFirstName>?</CustomerFirstName>
                <CustomerName>?</CustomerName>
                <AgreementNum>?</AgreementNum>
                <AgreedbyOwner>?</AgreedbyOwner>
                <OriginalReceived>?</OriginalReceived>
                <AgreementSignDate>?</AgreementSignDate>
                <BusinessContactFirstName>?</BusinessContactFirstName>
                <BusinessContactLastName>?</BusinessContactLastName>
                <UserID>?</UserID>
                <FMCMNPRequestId>?</FMCMNPRequestId>
                <LegalContactFirstName>?</LegalContactFirstName>
                <LegalContactLastName>?</LegalContactLastName>
                <CreatedBy>?</CreatedBy>
                <Comments>?</Comments>
                <IntegrationID>?</IntegrationID>
                <OrderId>?</OrderId>
                <ReferenceOrder>?</ReferenceOrder>
                <Status>?</Status>
                <OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>?</OrderTypeProvisioningRelevant>
                <TriggerScript>?</TriggerScript>
                <OrderSource>?</OrderSource>
                <CustomerSegment>?</CustomerSegment>
                <CustomerSubsegment>?</CustomerSubsegment>
                <CustomerIdNumber>?</CustomerIdNumber>
                <CustomerIdType>?</CustomerIdType>
                <Priority>?</Priority>
                <CustomerCode>?</CustomerCode>
                <Urgent>?</Urgent>
                <SalesPersonEmail>?</SalesPersonEmail>
                <NotificationPhoneNumber>?</NotificationPhoneNumber>
                <NotificationEmail>?</NotificationEmail>
                <ASAP>?</ASAP>
                <CustomerNotificationChannel>?</CustomerNotificationChannel>
                <OrderCreatorEmail>?</OrderCreatorEmail>
                <PrevCustomerRef>?</PrevCustomerRef>
                <VIPFlag>?</VIPFlag>
            </OrderInput>
        </ser:ServiceOrderToTechnicalOrderTransformerRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```